# Not able to figure out the working of setInterval()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, sorting

I have to sort the a bunch of vertical bars in ascending order. So I've coded that part well but the problem arises in when i'm trying to color the bars. I have generated a random bar list

[image]

So program takes the first two bars and colors them "red" and then swaps them and then the color gets back to "green". This continues till everything is sorted in ascending order. But the problem I am facing is that after everything gets sorted, the first two bars keep changing their color continuously from green to red. The first two bars keep changing their colors even after the stopped the setInterval() function.

Below is the code that implements these features in javascript

```
//Function to sort
reset();
$(".btn").click(function bubbleSort(){
  let flag=0;
  for(let i=0;i<values.length-1;i++){
  flag=0;
  for(let j=0;j<values.length-1-i;j++){
      var main=setInterval(function swap(){

        if(values[j]>values[j+1]){
          let temp=values[j];
          values[j]=values[j+1];
          values[j+1]=temp;
          flag=1;

        if(j==0){
            $(".line1").css({"background-color":"red"});
            $(".line2").css({"background-color":"red"});
            setTimeout(function(){
            $(".line1").css({"height":values[j],"background-color":"#357d35"});
            $(".line2").css({"height":values[j+1],"background-color":"#357d35"});
          },500);
          }

            else if(j==1){
            $(".line2").css({"background-color":"red"});
            $(".line3").css({"background-color":"red"});
            setTimeout(function(){
            $(".line2").css({"height":values[j],"background-color":"#357d35"});
            $(".line3").css({"height":values[j+1],"background-color":"#357d35"});
          },500);
          }

        else if(j==2){
            $(".line3").css({"background-color":"red"});
            $(".line4").css({"background-color":"red"});
            setTimeout(function(){
            $(".line3").css({"height":values[j],"background-color":"#357d35"});
            $(".line4").css({"height":values[j+1],"background-color":"#357d35"});
          },500);
          }
        }//end of if statement

        else{
          if(j==0){
                $(".line1").css({"background-color":"red"});
                $(".line2").css({"background-color":"red"});
              setTimeout(function(){
              $(".line1").css({"background-color":"#357d35"});
              $(".line2").css({"background-color":"#357d35"});
            },500);
            }
        } //end of else statement
        setTimeout(function(){
          clearInterval(main);
        },5000);
    },550*(j+3));

  }//end of 'j' loop

  if(flag==0)
    break;
  }//end of 'i' loop
});
```

I have tried various changes but somehow I am not able to stop the first two bars from flickering between red and green continuously.

Comment: The issue is *scope* - `var` is always the nearest `function` so there's one variable for the whole of `bubbleSort`.  Change it to `let main=setItnerval...` so you have a different instance for each loop.

Comment: @freedomn-m Dude come on mahn,I have been trying this for long and you literally solved it instantly xD.Thanks a lot !!!!

Comment: Sometimes just takes a 2nd pair of eyes.  :)